# How can i get dropdown value in custom services function in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-service

```
I have html page which containe dropdowns and submit button. Select a dropdown value and click on submit button How can i get dropdown value in javascript files custom service function in angularjs ? 

Here below is my html content:

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>E-cell</title>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script src="e_cell_services.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="e_cell.js"></script>-->
    <!--<script src="e_cell_services.js"></script>-->
    <script src="e2e.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function selectvalue(){

            var country_dropdown=document.getElementById("country");
            var country_Mcode=document.getElementById("country_mcode");
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="motoG")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="moto G"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="samasung")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="Samsung"
            }
        }

        function selectvalue1(){

            var country_dropdown=document.getElementById("country");
            var country_Mcode=document.getElementById("country_mcode");
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="20%")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="20%"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="50%")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="50%"
            }
        }

        function selectvalue2(){

            var country_dropdown=document.getElementById("country");
            var country_Mcode=document.getElementById("country_mcode");
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="p1")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="100 to 500"
            }
            if(document.getElementById("country").value=="p2")
            {
                document.getElementById("country_mcode").value="500 to 1000"
            }
        }


    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="myEapp">
    <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <table border="1">
        <tr >
            <td>
                <div>
                    <h4>Details</h4>
                </div>
            </td>
            <td rowspan="4">
                <div>
                    <h4>Welcome</h4>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p> manufacturing comprehensive assortment of
                        Electric Rickshaw, Battery Rickshaw, Electric
                        Passenger Rickshaw, Eco Friendly Rickshaw etc.,
                        We offer electric battery rickshaw which is
                        immensely appraised in the market for robust
                        construction, high performance, longer service
                        life, comfortable seats and low Maintenance.
                        These products are manufactured by using cutting edge technology and high grade components as per set Quality Standards.</p>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td>
            <div>

                <select name="country_name" class="country" onchange="selectvalue2()" ng-model="price">
                    <option value="" selected >Price</option>
                    <option value="p1">100 to 500</option>
                    <option value="p2">500 to 1000</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
            <div>

                <select name="country_name" class="country" onchange="selectvalue1()" ng-model="discount">
                    <option value="" selected >Discount</option>
                    <option value="20%">20%</option>
                    <option value="50%">50%</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </td></tr>

        <tr><td>
            <div>

                <select name="country_name" class="country" onchange="selectvalue()" ng-model="mobile">
                    <option value="" selected >Smart Phone</option>
                    <option value="motoG">moto G</option>
                    <option value="samasung">Samsung</option>
                </select>

            </div>
        </td></tr>
        <tr><td><input type="submit" value="submit"  ng-click="fun()"></td></tr>
        <div ng-bind-html="ppl"></div>{{ppl}}

    </table>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>


and my javascript file content is:

var product=angular.module('myApp',[]);


product.controller("myCtrl", function($scope,$http,$location,LSM){

    $scope.fun=function(){

        $http.post('#/product',{product:$scope.mobile ,price:$scope.price, discount:$scope.discount}).then (function(response){

            //product:$scope.mobile=[{one:'moto g',two:'samasung'}];
            //price:$scope.price=[{mini:100, max:500}];
            //discount:$scope.discount=[{mini:'20%', max:'50%'}];

            return $scope.ppl=response.data;
            // return $scope.ppl=$location.url();

        });


    }
});

product.service('LSM',function() {

        this.data=function(){
            return([{
                mobile:'moto g',
                price:'100 to 500',
                discount:'20% to 50%'
            }
            ])
        }
```

Ill pass value in controller also i want to pass the html value in services.Above u can see ill pass static value in product.services function but i want to get html page dropdown value in product.service's function like u can see above in product.controller($scope.mobile)..how can i do this?

Comment: can share you code

Answer (score 0):

Use angularjs way. Try like below.

```js
var app = angular.module('exApp', []);
  app.controller('controllerName', function($scope){
   //Here is selected price value is assign below scope variavle
   $scope.price = "";
  $scope.data = [{
                mobile:'moto g',
                price:'100 to 500',
                discount:'20% to 50%'
            },
             {
                mobile:'lenova',
                price:'100 to 500',
                discount:'20% to 50%'
            },
             {
                mobile:'samsung',
                price:'100 to 500',
                discount:'20% to 50%'
            }]
   $scope.selected = function(){
   console.log($scope.price);
   }
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.3/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="exApp" ng-controller="controllerName">
<div>
 <select ng-model="price" ng-change="selected()" ng-options="mob.mobile for mob in data"></select>
    
     <br> {{price}}
 </div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 Dropdown selection is use an ng-change event is get the your selected price value.

 Directive:  
 <div>
      <select name="country_name" class="country" on-change="selectvalue2()" ng-model="price">
      <option value="" selected >Price</option>
      <option value="p1">100 to 500</option>
      <option value="p2">500 to 1000</option>
      </select>
 </div> 
 Controller:
  app.controller('controllerName', function($scope){
   //Here is selected price value is assign below scope variavle
   $scope.price = "";
   $scope.selectValue2 = function(){
   alert($scope.price) 
   }
  })
```

Demo url : [sample dropdown selection](https://jsfiddle.net/e9r0rtsL/7/)

Comment: @vaishali bagul if have any queries ask me

Comment: Above ill share my code, can you answer this ? Thank you